# Strip all dashes in string for GUIDs only

Tags: mysql, sql, uuid, guid

I don't want to replace ALL dashes in a string, but rather replace only those dashes that are part of a GUID/UUID.

**Before the replace:**

> Mary-Anne Smith is a physics professor at the University of Illinois. Her dissertation was focused on the Higgs-Boson particle. Her professor ID is 01140384-5189-11ed-beb7-fa163e98fdf8. You can reach her at mary-annes@ui.edu.

**After the replace:**

> Mary-Anne Smith is a physics professor at the University of Illinois. Her dissertation was focused on the Higgs-Boson particle. Her professor ID is 01140384518911edbeb7fa163e98fdf8. You can reach her at mary-annes@ui.edu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `Regexp_Replace`

```
Select Regexp_Replace
('string', 
'[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a- 
 z0-9]{12}', '-','') from table;
```

If we go by the sematics of the data we can also split it on "id is"

Eg

```
Select 
 Replace(Substr(string 
  Instr(String, 
 'Id is' 
  )+1,Instr(String, 
 'Id is' 
  )+1+len(hexIdformat), 
  '-','')
```

Something like this above.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL 8.x, you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` to get the UUID from the string, remove the dashes, and replace it with that.

```
SELECT REPLACE(
    column,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '[0-9a-f]+-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]+'),
    REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '[0-9a-f]+-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]+'), '-', '')) AS column_modified
FROM yourTable
```

Note that this will only replace the first UUID in the column. If you need to do more replacements, you could write a stored function that repeats the replacement in a loop.

Comment: Isn't it better to have a regex that just looks for 4 hex digits between the dashes instead of more than one.  ({4} instead of +)

Comment: Probably, although I doubt there will be any other sets of 5 hex strings connected by dashes, so a false positive is extremely unlikely.

Comment: That is true...